# How to make wildfly console to print japanese text using system.out.println();

Tags: java, encoding, command-prompt, wildfly-10

While printing below Japanese text in wildfly console the content is displayed as

```
System.out.println("世界您好!");
15:12:36,220 INFO  [stdout] (default task-43) ????!
```

Below are the suggestion tried.

1)Started the wildfly server with below configuration
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8

2) changed cmd prompt font to Lucida console fonts and started with chcp 65001 before proceeding with server start command.

Read the below in many articles " console support UTF encoding and make sure your compiler is configured to compile using UTF8.".

Can anyone guide how to ensure the console support utf?.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried using a logger instead of `System.out.println`? Also what OS are you running on?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes ,Same result with logger too.ie)????! printed in log. Os detail:Windows 7

Comment: Have you checked the server.log? I don't know much about the Windows console, but it works fine for me on Linux. My shell is set to use UTF-8.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes same in server log. I need to display in windows.